# Force branch to become the master

Tags: git, github, github-desktop

I messed something up on the main branch that is causing many errors, the good news is I have a branch that has everything on the master branch + a feature that is 100% working. Being new to GIT I don't know the best way to go about this but how do I force that working branch to become the master branch? I've tried a pull request but it says that there is nothing to compare (even though there are some needed frameworks missing from the master).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+make+the+current+branch+master

Answer (score 1):

`git branch -f master feature_branch` : this will rewrite the local master branch with your feature branch

`git push remote +feature_branch:master` : this will rewrite remote branch.

Comment: Tried that but got these errors when running the second command: ```fatal: 'remote' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.```

Comment: try with origin in place of remote.  git push origin +feature_branch:master